# Calculating angle between two points in C++, getting weird results

Tags: c++, opencv, trigonometry

I am trying to calculate the angle between two points using OpenCV C++ in visual studio 2013. One point is a tracked object and the other is the position where i clicked my mouse. However with my code i am getting a very long and fluctuating answer that does not seem correct...

Code extract:

```C++
float angle = (atan2(mousex - posX, mousey - posY) * 180) / 3.14159265;
                sprintf_s(textA, "%d", angle);
                putText(imgOriginal, textA, Point(posX, posY + 20),
    FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.8, Scalar(200, 200, 250), 1, CV_AA);
```

I have included  and  but still no result.

I get results that fluctuate (while in the same spot) between 50368 and 10732.

So if anyone could help my out it would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: `atan2` takes the y component first. If you're passing the parameters in the wrong order, you're computing the angle rotated by 90°. Besides, your angle is a float, so using `%d` in your `sprintf` will output garbage.

Comment: @LeleGriccioli Please accept the answer I have posted (don't worry, it's community wiki, so I won't get any points for it) so that people viewing your question from the main page will know that it's answered.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of problems with your code.

As @kuroineko mentioned in comments:

`atan2` takes the y component first. If you're passing the parameters in the wrong order, you're computing the angle rotated by 90°. Besides, your angle is a `float`, so using `%d` in your `sprintf` will output garbage.